# Strange font size problem in Chrome mobile

Tags: google-chrome

I cannot guess the reason why the HTML below displays two of the `<p>` elements in a smaller font size in Chrome mobile -- the only difference seems to be the content of the elements. There is no CSS, just the default browser rendering. Is this a bug? Is there actually a reason for this behaviour? Completely baffled by this, any help is appreciated.

Here's the HTML code, and [you can see it online here](http://ozarfreo.ende.cc/test.html). Browse it with Chrome mobile to see the issue. The rendering I see looks like this:
[image: rendering in Chrome mobile]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test page</title>
  </head>
<body>

  <h1>Test page</h1>

  <p>
  Testing</p>

  <p>Testing
  Testing</p>

  <p>Testing
    Testing
  Testing</p>

  <p>Testing
    Testing
    Testing
  Testing</p>

  <p>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
  </p>

  <p><a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a></p>

  <p><a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a></p>

  <p><a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a></p>

  <p><a href="#">Testing</a>
    Testing</p>


  <p><a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    Testing</p>


  <p><a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    Testing</p>

      <p><a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    Testing</p>

    <p><a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    <a href="#">Testing</a>
    Testing
    Testing</p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: By the way, I'm using Chrome version 46.0.2490.76 in Android, in a Samsung Galaxy S4.

Answer (score 0):

Using emulation mode (in Chrome/Windows) also gives the same error.
You should report it as a bug.
According to the Dev Console of Chrome there is no hidden CSS or whatsoever affecting the font-size (or any other CSS property for that matter).
Note: Why do you have an empty style tag in the head section? If you set the default font-size for p there, does the bug happen?